# can i send email from any alias of domain i own with aws ses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I pretty confused with sending emails I am using AWS-SES for sending email and I have verified custom domain my question is can I send email from any alias for that particular domain ex:- `newalias@domain-i-own.com` but without the email id actually exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html):

> When you verify an entire domain, you are verifying all email
>   addresses from that domain, so you don't need to verify email
>   addresses from that domain individually. For example, if you verify
>   the domain example.com, you can send email from user1@example.com,
>   user2@example.com, or any other user atexample.com.

This basically means that, once you have verified your domain, SES will accept and alias @example.com as the from address; SES has no knowledge if that alias actually exists or not, you may in fact have a catch-all where the alias doesn’t technically exist, so as long as you’ve verified the domain it allows you to specify any address as the from address.